# Type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<int>' where

Tags: json, list, flutter, dart, dynamic

I am new to Flutter, I try to run one GitHub project but got an error like:

> type List dynamic is not a subtype of type List int where.

[Github Link](https://github.com/aaronoe/FlutterCinematic)

**Error Line**

```
List<int> genreIds;

MediaItem._internalFromJson(Map jsonMap, {MediaType type: MediaType.movie})
      :
        type = type,
        id = jsonMap["id"].toInt(),
        voteAverage = jsonMap["vote_average"].toDouble(),
        title = jsonMap[(type == MediaType.movie ? "title" : "name")],
        posterPath = jsonMap["poster_path"] ?? "",
        backdropPath = jsonMap["backdrop_path"] ?? "",
        overview = jsonMap["overview"],
        releaseDate = jsonMap[(type == MediaType.movie
            ? "release_date"
            : "first_air_date")],

        genreIds = jsonMap["genre_ids"];//in this line

}
```

[Above code File](https://github.com/aaronoe/FlutterCinematic/blob/master/lib/model/mediaitem.dart)

Answer (score 165, accepted):

Change

```
genreIds = jsonMap["genre_ids"];
```

to

```
genreIds = jsonMap["genre_ids"].cast<int>();
```

types in JSON maps or lists don't have concrete generic types.
`genreIds` requires a `List<int>` not a `List` (or `List<dynamic>`), therefore you need to bring the value to its required type before you can assign it.

If you haven't seen this error earlier for the same code, then it's probably because you upgraded to a Dart version where `--preview-dart-2` became the default (it was opt-in previously)

Comment: Is this still valid? There doesn't seem to be the cast functions in List<dynamic>

Comment: `cast` existed only for a short time. See https://github.com/dart-lang/site-www/issues/736 for more details.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer if cast only existed for short time what should be used now? in my case I'm trying to cast List<dynamic> to List<DocumentReference> and "as" does not work and still have to use ".cast" ?

Comment: Did you check the link in my comment just before yours? Perhaps `new List<DocumentReference>(myDynamicList)`

Comment: Every day I search something related to Flutter / Dart, I am having better understanding from your answer, Sir. Thank you. Related to @paresh 's answer, we can use null-aware operator such as : `genreIds = jsonMap["genre_ids"]?.cast<int>();`

Answer (score 56):

A more elegant way could also be initialising new List instead of casting.

```
var genreIdsFromJson = jsonMap['genre_ids'];
List<int> genreIdsList = new List<int>.from(genreIdsFromJson);

// then you can use gendreIdsList to the mapping function
// ...

gendreIds = genreIdsList
...
```

Update:
[As per the documentation](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-core/List/List.from.html)

``
All the elements should be instances of E. The elements iterable itself may have any element type, so this constructor can be used to down-cast a List, for example as:

```
List<SuperType> superList = ...;
List<SubType> subList =
    new List<SubType>.from(superList.whereType<SubType>());
```

This constructor creates a growable list when growable is true; otherwise, it returns a fixed-length list.
``

Update: **Why is it better to initialize than to cast? (Pros / Cons)**

Explicit Conversions (Casting): The process is usually associated with information loss or failure to convert between types

Creating new immutable elements is better than casting. Revealing type-related bugs at compile time, more readable code, more maintainable code, better ahead of time (AOT) compilation.

i.e. it is better to try parse or parse a value with predefined method because if the type does not match the value will be null. On the other hand explicitly casting an object or value can throw errors at runtime.

Comment: Or even List<int>.from(genreIdsFromJson ?? []) to handle the case when there is no elements for 'genre_ids' key of the map

Comment: You can add some validation to the method from(genreIdsFromJson) method. Depending on the situation you can either check before returning the corresponding object or return a default value (maybe null / empty string) with inline conditionals e.g. FooType.from(json['genreIdsFromJson']) ? FooType.from(json['genreIdsFromJson']) : null.

Comment: This is a very interesting answer, would you mind adding the pros/cons compared to cast? Thanks!

Comment: @Edi how does your answer change under null-safety? I still had to add a cast for the json lookup in order to satisfy the compiler: `List<Int>.from(jsonMap['genre_ids'] as List)` and also make a null check before accessing the map entry.

Comment: `List.from` is a good solution.

Answer (score 9):

A shorter way to handle is

```
genreIds = (jsonMap["genre_ids"] as List)?.map((e) => e as int)?.toList();
```

Answer (score 8):

Given all the solutions. I would like to add many other different ways of achieving the same

1. `List<int> genreIds = List<int>.from(source);`
2. `List<int> ints = List.castFrom<dynamic, int>(source);`
3. `List<int> ints = source.cast<int>();`
4. `List<int> ints = source.map((e) => e as int).toList();`

For this use case you can write:

`List<int> genreIds = List<int>.from(jsonMap["genre_ids"]);`

Hope it helps! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you still unsuccess like me, try:

`List<int> genreIds = List<int>.from(json.decode(jsonMap["genre_ids"]));`

Answer (score 0):

I hit this problem because I used generics in my api lib.  Here's how I worked around it:

```
// I've simplified the get for clarity.  My production lib wraps http so I can set / handle base url, headers, time out, and throw when error codes are returned.

Future<T> get<T>(String resource) async {
  var c = Completer<T>();
  try {
    var uri = Uri.parse('$baseUrl/$resource');
    var response = await http.get(uri);
    T result = json.decode(response.body);
    c.complete(result);
  } catch (e) {
    c.completeError(e);
  }
  return c.future;
}

// Service from my feature lib
Future<Iterable<MyDTO>> fetch() async {
  var c = Completer<Iterable<MyDTO>>();
  try {
    List<MyDTO> result = [];        
    // Use Iterable<dynamic> since we cannot use generics to cast when decoding the response body
    var body = await api.get<Iterable<dynamic>>('my-resource');
    
    // cast to List<Map<String, dynamic>
    var myDTOMaps = List<Map<String, dynamic>>.from(body);

    for (var e in myDTOMaps) {
      MyDTO dto = MyDTO.fromMap(e);
      result.add(dto);
    }
    c.complete(result);
  } catch (e) {
    c.completeError(e);
  }
  return c.future;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know how your data is, you could just check the first item type to know if the list is filled with strings or other like:

```dart
if (errors is List && errors.isNotEmpty && errors.first is String) {
    return List<String>.from(errors);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I got a similar error using json setting properties. I fixed it with this:

```
jsonMap["propId"][0] as int
```

They are single properties, so the 0 is always correct.

Comment: This is not even remotely connected to this problem.