# Flutter: Convert list of integers to list of strings in one liner

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I was trying to parse a JSON to my object.
One field of json contains [1,2,3,4] which is a list of int s.
But my objects field contain `List<String> members;` for that field. How can I convert this.

Usually for converting ["1","2","3"] to List, I used to do `json['members'].cast<String>()`.

Is there a similar one liner available other than using map ?

Comment: Did you Try .toString ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using map is quite efficient in this case :

```dart
List<String> members = json['members'].map((el) => el.toString()).toList();
```

Or, since Dart 2.3, combining map and [spread operator](https://dart.dev/language/collections#spread-operators) :

```dart
List<String> members = [...json['members'].map((el) => el.toString())];
```

If you really do not want to use map, you could also use [collection for](https://dart.dev/language/collections#control-flow-operators) :

```dart
List<String> members = [for(int i = 0; i < json['members'].length; i++) json['members'][i].toString()];
```

Comment: Updated answer (see [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50245187/type-listdynamic-is-not-a-subtype-of-type-listint-where))

Comment: Good, however you could write `map((el) => el.toString())` instead of `map((el) { return el.toString(); })` for more simplicity