# FLUTTER: When converting List<int> to List<String> error thrown: Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' in type cast

Tags: list, flutter, sharedpreferences, tostring

This is bizarre, I'm trying to do a simple conversion of List to List sp I can save it to SharedPreferences (prefs) and it throws an exception.

> Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' in type cast

I've tried various other less familiar formalisations of the conversion as found on Stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59676655/flutter-convert-list-of-integers-to-list-of-strings-in-one-liner), but the exception persists

```
else if (value is List<int>) {
      prefs.setStringList(
          "itemsToLoanCats", [...value.map((int e) => e.toString())]);
    }
```

I'm now wondering if the error isn't what it seems and something less obvious is going on.

Love some help.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood, you should remove int `(int e)=>` to be `(e)=>`

```
else if (value is List<int>) {
      prefs.setStringList(
          "itemsToLoanCats", [...value.map((e) =>e.toString())]);
    }
```