# How do I correctly cast a dynamic list to a List<List<String>> without runtime errors when .cast() has no effect?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm receiving data in a [`MethodCall`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/MethodCall-class.html) object, which means that I **cannot** receive it as any type other than `dynamic`:

```dart
dynamic listOfObjects = methodCall.arguments;
```

but because I am the one sending the data from the platform-specific code, I know that the data is **guaranteed** to be of type `List<List<String>>`.

I want to inflate this data into a collection of concrete Dart object types:

```dart
List<DartObject> dartObjects =
    methodCall.arguments.map((raw) => DartObject(
          prop1: raw[0],
          prop2: raw[1],
          prop3: raw[2],
        )).toList();
```

but this code fails with this error:

> type '`List<dynamic>`' is not a subtype of type '`List<String>`' in type cast

I've tried extensively to solve this issue on my own:

- [Dart's own documentation on fixing common type problems](https://dart.dev/guides/language/sound-problems#invalid-casts),
- [responses to similar Flutter issues](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/18979#issuecomment-401625017), and
- [answers to similar Stack Overflow questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50245597/4877269)

all say to use the List's `cast()` method, but even this falls over at runtime with the same error:

```dart
(call.arguments as List).cast<List<String>>()
// => type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<String>' in type cast
```

I'm sure I must be missing something obvious at this point.  What am I doing wrong?

**In short, how do I correctly cast to `List<List<String>>` without copying everything into a new data structure (i.e. without the use of `.from` or `.map`)?**

Comment: Have you tried `List<String>.from()`?

Comment: @AugustinR, I'm mindful that `List.from` would clone the entire existing list, which seems like an excessive solution to a type problem.

Comment: @AndreiCaisim, I'm dealing with a list of lists, so unless I have misunderstood your suggestion, this would cause me to replace lists with string representations of those lists, which I wouldn't be able to use.

Answer (score 0):

The following code should work:

```
(call.arguments as List<dynamic>).map((e) => (e as List<dynamic>).cast<String>())
```

Comment: I appreciate your response but unless I'm mistaken, this is **copying** the values into a new data structure rather than recasting.  Is it simply impossible to cast in-place?

Comment: There's no copy unless you use a `.toList()`.