# 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<String>'

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am doing a firestore query to a Map<String, List and save it into a variable called permissions. I nedd to iterate throught that maps keys which are Strings and tried the options below

```
   List<String> permissionsAllowed = permissions.keys.toList().map((key)=> 
   key.toString()).toList()

   List<String> permissionsAllowed = permissions.keys.toList().map<String>((key)=> 
   key.toString()).toList()


   List<String> permissionsAllowed = permissions.keys.map((key)=> key.toString()).toList()

   for (int i = 0; i < permissions.keys.toList().length; i++) {
           print(permissions.keys.toList()[i]);
           if (permissions.keys.toList()[i].runtimeType == String) {
             featuresAllowed.add(permissions.keys.toList()[i]);
      }
   }
```

none have worked any help is appreciated

```
  print(permissions.keys.toList());
  OUTPUT: [inventory, sales]
```

thank you for taking the time

Comment: have you tried type casting?

Comment: I had however I just updated and added a different error I got when trying to map

Comment: After your edit you forgot toList() `permissions.keys.toList().map(...).toList();`

Comment: `List<String> permissionsAllowed = permissions.keys.toList() as List<String>` ... you can try this.

Comment: I did forget sorry, removed it and will try the solution provided

Comment: problem was solved thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<int>' where](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50245187/type-listdynamic-is-not-a-subtype-of-type-listint-where)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use `List.from` like this

```
List<String> permissionsAllowed = List<String>.from(permissions.keys.toList());
```

Comment: If a key is not a `String` this gives the exception `type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String'`.

Comment: yes , this is assuming all dynamic data is string , if your data have variants then you have to do a type check , or convert them to string before passing to  `List.from`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but are you trying to find which keys are `String`? If so the method for `featuresAllow2` below works:

```
main(List<String> args) {
  var permissions = {
    'key1': 'value1',
    'key2': 'value2',
    1: 'one',
    2: 'two',
  };
  List<String> featuresAllow = permissions.keys.toList().map((key) {
    return key.toString();
  }).toList();
  print('featuresAllow= $featuresAllow');
  List<String?> featuresAllow2 = permissions.keys
      .toList()
      .map((key) {
        if (key is String) return key;
      })
      .where((key) => key != null)
      .toList();
  print('featuresAllow2= $featuresAllow2');
}
```

The code:

```
List<String> permissionsAllowed = List<String>.from(permissions.keys.toList());
```

gives an exception if a key is not a `String`.