# In API get method, I am encountering the error 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<String>'

Tags: flutter, flutter-futurebuilder

Here goes the Questions class which is used further in the list

```
class Questions {
  final String question;
  final String correctAnswer;
  final incorrectAnswers;

  Questions(
      {required this.question,
      required this.correctAnswer,
      required this.incorrectAnswers});
}
```

This is the API get block. The List with the type Questions is declared and then the items are appended

```
 List<Questions> questions = [];
  Future<List<Questions>> getRequest() async {
    final String url =
        'https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10&category=${widget.selectedItem[1]}&difficulty=${widget.selectedItem[0].toLowerCase()}&type=multiple';
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
    var responseData = jsonDecode(response.body.toString());
    // var responseData = json.decode(response.body);

    //Creating a list to store input data;
    for (var eachquestion in responseData["results"]) {
      Questions fquestion = Questions(
          question: eachquestion["question"],
          correctAnswer: eachquestion["correct_answer"],
          incorrectAnswers: eachquestion["incorrect_answers"]);

      //Adding user to the list.
      questions.add(fquestion);
    }
    return questions;
  }
```

and this one is the implementation of the Future builder

Also, the FutureBuilder lines shows that "type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<String>'"

```
FutureBuilder(
            future: getRequest(),
            builder: ((context, snapshot) {
              if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                return const Text("Loading...");
              } else {
                String answer = questions[indexVal].correctAnswer;
                List<String> options = [questions[indexVal].correctAnswer] +
                    questions[indexVal].incorrectAnswers;
                options.shuffle;
                return Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 150, 15, 0),
                    child: Column(
                        children: (num == 10)
                            ? [
                                ScorePage(
                                  score: score,
                                )
                              ]
                            : [
                                Container(
                                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 30),
                                  child: Center(
                                    child: Row(
                                      crossAxisAlignment:
                                          CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                      mainAxisAlignment:
                                          MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                      children: [
                                        Expanded(
                                          child: Text(
                                              questions[indexVal].question,
                                              style: const TextStyle(
                                                  fontSize: 20,
                                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Column(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                  children: [
                                    indOption(
                                        nextQues: nextQues,
                                        optionVal: options[0]),
                                    indOption(
                                        nextQues: nextQues,
                                        optionVal: options[1]),
                                    indOption(
                                        nextQues: nextQues,
                                        optionVal: options[2]),
                                    indOption(
                                        nextQues: nextQues,
                                        optionVal: options[3]),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ]));
              }
            }),
          )
```

Also, let me know the reason and solution behind it!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your model's
`incorrectAnswers` field. Its data type is dynamic so you have to type cast it as below.

```
List<String> options = [questions[indexVal].correctAnswer] +
                    questions[indexVal].incorrectAnswers as string;
```

Comment: It still didn't helped and it shows that it can't be added to the list

Comment: Use add() method instead off +

Answer (score 0):

As the other answer pointed out, the biggest problem is the type of your Questions class. This is what you should change it to (I also changed the name to `Question` since the object stores *one* question and not multiple):

```
class Question {
  final String question;
  final String correctAnswer;
  final List<String> incorrectAnswers;

  Questions(
      {required this.question,
      required this.correctAnswer,
      required this.incorrectAnswers});
}
```

Now, inside the `FutureBuilder` you need to combine the single correct answer with the x incorrect ones into one list of options, like this:

```
List<String> options = [
  questions[indexVal].correctAnswer,
  ...questions[indexVal].incorrectAnswers 
 // The three dots means since incorrectAnswers is a list and you don't want a list of lists,
 // it should take out the values and put them to the outer list one by one.
];
```

If you get the similar error again, keep in mind that you might need to typecast the values from the API in your constructor:

```
Question fquestion = Question(
    question: eachquestion["question"] as String,
    correctAnswer: eachquestion["correct_answer"] as String,
    incorrectAnswers: eachquestion["incorrect_answers"] as List<String>,
);
```

This should do the trick!

Comment: I would like to ask one more question. On using the options.shuffle(), it is shuffling the elements in real-time, i.e., when the user comes to that place. What shall be done to ensure that it shuffles and then build the widget? Now, it building and then shuffling.

Comment: Also, on using "final List<String> incorrectAnswers;", the page stucks at Loading and it seems that no response were received from the API and removing List<String> works normal

Comment: In your question it says `options.shuffle`, that is what you're using, yes? That shuffles the list in place, which means you don't need to make a new one. Since you're doing it before returning the container it should shuffle them before it shows them on screen. Did you also change the `FutureBuilder` to the code I provided? If you `print(options)` you should see them change every time you make the API request

Comment: Yeah, I change the FutureBuilder part and now it works fine. But regarding the shuffle part, the list shuffles as expected but in front of the user that is in the UI. Suppose a question loads with 4 options, these 4 options are of the same order and then after a seconds the options changes their order, in other word, they gets shuffled.

Comment: That sounds like the `FutureBuilder` is being ran twice. I'm not sure I can tell the reason from the code provided here, I'm sorry. Since you don't want questions being fetched on each rebuild, you could check out [this medium article](https://medium.flutterdevs.com/explore-futurebuilder-in-flutter-9744203b2b8c) to learn how to use `FutureBuilder` with a `Future` (ran only once) instead of a `async method`` (ran on every rebuild).

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the list of incorrectAnswers was dynamic and I was adding that to the List of type string. So I added the individual element of the list. Since it is not a scalable method, I would like to hear more advices from the geeks.

Comment: You could cast the list instead. https://stackoverflow.com/a/58529678/9930734 please check out the link for more clarity.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).